# parse_url() does not parse a specific url

Tags: php

I've got a Problem with PHP `parse_url()`.

My url looks like:

```
$url = "_search?q=sku:89399";
var_dump(parse_url($url));
```

According to this, `var_dump()` returns `bool(false)` saying this is not a correct url.

But using an url like this works?!

```
$url = "_search?q=sku:202490";
var_dump(parse_url($url));
```

`var_dump()` returns `array(2) { ["path"]=> string(7) "_search" ["query"]=> string(12) "q=sku:202490" }`

So do you have any idea, why *sku:202490* works and and *sku:89399* does not ?

Thank you so much!

**UPDATE:**
Thank you all for your comments. According to the first few comments, i can confirm that the number is being interpreted as port number if it has 5 or less digits. So if a number with 5 or less digits is bigger than *65535* `parse_url()` will not work.

Comment: RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that `89399` falls within the valid range of values that could be identified as a port (if it checks for number of digits), but that `"_search?q=sku` is not valid as a protocol, so it complains

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah but according to the manual i see no reason why *202490* should work and *89399* not ... thank you

Comment: Whereas `202490` cannot be mistaken for a port number, so the function continues checking

Comment: `parse_url` manual entry mentions that partial URLs are also accepted

Comment: Alex - this is pushing the minimum limits of what might be considered partial for a url though

Comment: `89399` is not a port. maximum port value can be `65535`. Why did somebody downvoted it. its a good question and can help other people too.

Comment: @MarkBaker The main problem is, the LSWeb Guzzle Bundle i am using this seperating the URL just like that and checking those parts seperated

Comment: Note that php7 does parse both correctly

Comment: It's certainly the colon followed by a value that's throwing it; if you replace that colon with a dot, they both parse correctly

Comment: @AshishChoudhary - if it's using a regexp as simple as `:\d{1,5}` then it doesn't explicitly check the port number range

Comment: This is not something to do with 1 to 5 digits. As `10000` also qualifies. There is a certain range which throws this. I'm Wondering why...

Comment: this is a bug of sorts, there are a couple of bug reports regarding this, fixed in PHP7. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55511 (PHP 5.4), https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66813 (PHP 5.5.9). Fix is here https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/e49922d3f8060e47f810a24ce48d4e622b493699

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the possibility to set a "dummy" scheme to the specific url:

**Example #1**

```
$url = "_search?q=sku:89399";
var_dump(parse_url("test://".$url));
```

**Output #1**

```
array(3) {
    ["scheme"]=> string(4) "test"
    ["host"]=> string(7) "_search"
    ["query"]=> string(11) "q=sku:89399"
}
```

Your code is working for PHP >= 7.0.0 beta1!

**Example #2**

```
$url = "_search?q=sku:89399";
var_dump(parse_url($url));
```

**Output #2 (PHP version >= 7.0.0 beta1)**

```
array(2) {
    ["path"]=> string(7) "_search"
    ["query"]=> string(11) "q=sku:89399"
}
```

**Output #2 (PHP version < 7.0.0 beta1)**

```
bool(false)
```

With the above information, it is possible to write a own function to do this. Try the following one:

```
<?php
function custom_parse_url($url) {
    if (version_compare(phpversion(), '7.0.0beta1') < 0) {
        return parse_url('test://'.$url);
    } else {
        return parse_url($url);
    }
}

$url = "_search?q=sku:89399";
var_dump(custom_parse_url($url));
```

Here you can find a working example: https://3v4l.org/dN2bP

Comment: If all you want is the *query*, then this is a workaround. Otherwise, the parse result is simply incorrect with the dummy scheme.

Comment: Yes of course, but you could extend the function to give one more parameter to define the dummy scheme. Into the function you can remove the scheme if value equals the second parameter.